Can't have Designer to resize Qwidget inside QGridLayout in pyqt5?
I can run this code:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QScrollArea, QWidget, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag



class MainWidget(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        
        
        self.setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;") 
        
        
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        
        self.resize(600, 400)
        
        
        # for i in [(0,0) , (0,1) , (1,0) , (1,1)]:
            
        for i in [(0,0)]:
            
            
            
            print(str(i))
            
            wig = QWidget()
            
            wig.resize(150,100)
            
            
            
            
            # VBox = QVBoxLayout()
            
            # VBox.addStretch(1)
            
            
            # VBox.addWidget(label)
            
            # wig.setLayout(VBox)
            
            
            scroll = QScrollArea(wig)
            
            scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
            

            scrollAreaWidgetContents = QWidget()
            

            # label = QLabel()
            
            # font = self.font()
            
            
            # font.setPointSize(15)
            
            # label.setFont(font)
            
            # label.setText(str(i)+'   ')
            
            # VBox = QVBoxLayout()
            
            # VBox.addWidget(label)
            
            # scrollAreaWidgetContents.setLayout(VBox)
            
            scroll.setWidget(scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            
            
            self.layout.addWidget(scroll, i[0] , i[1])
            
        
        
        self.show()
    
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


and be able to resize my widget together with the widgets contained in the QGridlayout.
While using PyQt-Designer to write my app (test003.ui), after converting via pyuic5 I get:
test003.py:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(658, 538)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
        Form.setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: yellow\n"
"}")
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 10, 641, 501))
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetNoConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 614, 495))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color: blue}")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

and with main code:
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QScrollArea, QWidget, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout


from PyQt5 import QtGui

from PyQt5.QtGui import QDrag


# from untitled001 import Ui_Form

# from untitled002 import Ui_Form

# from untitled003b import Ui_Form

# from test001 import Ui_Form # form


# from test002 import Ui_Form #form + grid

from test003 import Ui_Form #form + grid + widget


class MainWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    
    # w.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

but I get:

where the blue widget doesn't resize together with main one:

What am I doing wrong? I wasn't able to find any hint in PyQt designer and reading out the test003.py ui.

For future reference, whenever the issue is strictly related to Designer, consider to directly provide the ui file, not the pyuic code.

Ok., wanted to make easier toncopy and run code. And resd someehere that import is better because faster than loadUI

Speed is only one benefit, not the only one nor the most important. For instance, directly using the ui is simpler as it requires one file less for each ui, and you also don't have to regenerate the py files every single time the ui is changed. Besides, what's important here is that we must be able to easily access the ui to understand the problem, and being able to load it in Designer makes it much simpler than having to read the whole python file.

found an answer here : pyqt5 : Unable to maximize widgets on Window resize
quote of one of the comments:

You're only setting layouts for the "layout widgets" you're creating, but those widget are not managed by a parent layout, which is what should be set on the central widget. Right click on an empty area outside any other widget, and select the appropriate layout from the "Lay out" submenu. –

here Designer working solution for example of my app:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(704, 500)
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.scrollArea_1 = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(Form)
        self.scrollArea_1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea_1.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea_1.setObjectName("scrollArea_1")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 667, 484))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setStyleSheet("")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget{border: 3px solid red}\n"
"\n"
"QWidget{background-color: green}")
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.scrollArea_1.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea_1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

pic:

